# Bubble sort, Selection sort, and insertion sort

Tags: c++, sorting, bubble-sort, insertion-sort, selection-sort

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvWSG.jpg

This is the link that shows the result.

And this result is how my result of C++ must be like

As this result shows, there are Bubble sort, Selection Sort, and Insertion Sort,

and every process of each sort is shown to the black screen.

For example, (Bubble Sort)

20     10     40     30

20     10     30     40

10     20     30     40.

I have to use `void displayPtrArray` to show like that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void reset(int array[], const int size);
void displayIntArray();
void displayPtrArray(const int array[], int size);
void BubbleSort(int array[], int size);
void SelectionSort(int array[], int size);
void InsertionSort(int a[], int size);

const int RR = 4;

int main()
{
    int arr[RR];
    reset(arr, RR);

}

void reset(int array[], const int size)
{
    cout << "The originial array has been reset to:" << endl;
    int array[RR] = { 20, 40, 10, 30 };

    for (int n = 0; n < size; n++)
    {
        cout << setw(5) << array[n];
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

void displayPtrArray(const int array[], int size)
{
}

void displayIntArray()
{
}

void BubbleSort(int array[], int size)
{
    bool swap;
    int temp;

    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for (int count = 0; count < (size - 1); count++)
        {
            if (array[count] > array[count + 1])
            {
                temp = array[count];
                array[count] = array[count + 1];
                array[count + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swap);
}

void selectionSort(int array[], int size)
{
    int startScan, minIndex, minValue;

    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = array[startScan];
        for (int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
        {
            if (array[index] < minValue)
            {
                minValue = array[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
        array[startScan] = minValue;
    }
}

void InsertionSort(int a[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 1; i<size; i++)
    {
        int j;
        int current = a[i];
        for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && a[j]> current; j--)
        {
            a[j + 1] = a[j];
        }
        a[j + 1] = current;
    }
}
```

I use the function for every sort, but if that is wrong please tell me.

And teach me how to show the process of each sort with

```
void displayPtrArray
```

I really don't know..... T_T...........

PLEASE HELP !!

Comment: If you want to see the process, just output the array in between of the sorting process.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, viewing the process of the sorting is rather simple. You just have to output during the sorting process. You don't need to call another function for that. Try something like this

```
void BubbleSort(int array[], int size)
{
    bool swap;
    int temp;

    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for (int count = 0; count < (size); count++)
        {
            if (array[count] > array[count + 1])
            {
                temp = array[count];
                array[count] = array[count + 1];
                array[count + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;

            }
           cout << "\nThe array is ";
           for ( int i = 0; i < ( size - 1 ); i++ )
           cout << array[i] << "\t";                            // Look here
           cout << "\nThe value of temp is " << temp << endl;   // and here
        }
    } while (swap);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have the exact code you need for displayPtrArray! The `for` loop defined in reset should do it.

Looking at the expected output, the array gets displayed every time there's a change to it. For bubble sort, the array changes when you do your swap (at the end of the if statement), so you want to add your call to displayPtrArray in the line after `swap = true`.

For selection sort, the array changes at the end of your outer for loop, so you should add the call to displayPtrArray in the line after `array[startScan] = minValue;`.

For insertion sort, the array changes at every iteration of the inner for loop and also in the last line of the outer for loop, so you'll probably have to call displayPtrArray in both of those places.

Note: just in case you aren't familiar with the syntax, you call the function like this: `displayPtrArray(array, size);` where `array` is the name of your array variable (the name is `array` in bubble and selection sorts; it's `a` in insertion sort) and `size` is the size of the array (named consistently in all three of your sorting functions).